# How to assign an array to a struct in C

Tags: c

Say I have a simple struct, such as this one:

```
struct myStruct {

   uint8_t arr[10];
};
```

All I want to be able to do is to modify the contents of that array. However, it seems that I cannot assign the array directly (ie, I can't do something like pointerToThisStruct->arr = anArrayofSizeTen).

So here is my main method:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    uint8_t test[10] = {0};
    myStruct *struc;
    struc->arr = test; //can't do this
    memcpy(struc->arr, test, sizeof(test));
}
```

Now, I understand that direct copying over won't work, but why is memcpy also giving me a segfault? How exactly am I supposed to modify the struct array?

Comment: You are segfaulting because you create a pointer to a struct. Instead of myStruct *struc; use myStruct struc and reference the member "arr" with struc.arr.

Comment: @Chimera does that make a difference? I was under the impression that the arrow sign -> was the same thing as deferencing the pointer and then using the "."

Comment: You've got a pointer... but what is it pointing *at*?  You don't have the actual struct.

Comment: @earre1990 Your use of the dereferencing operator (the arrow) is correct, but you've never allocated the memory for the struct. You only asked for memory for a *pointer*, which means that pointer is pointed at uninitialized memory. Attempting to copy to memory that the OS hasn't allocated to you causes the segfault.

Comment: earre1990: yes, it does really make a difference. A pointer has the value of an memory address. It doesn't really contain the 'object'. You can create the struct as @Chimera said, or allocate memory to your struct.

Comment: you have myStruct* struc; and you try to access struc->arr without ever allocating memory for it.

Comment: Yes, `a->b` is the same as `(*a).b`, but the important difference here would be on the line `myStruct struc;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare an actual `myStruct`. Not a pointer to one. Declaring a pointer to one doesn't actually allocate any memory for the struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

struct myStruct {

   uint8_t arr[10];
};


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int i;
    uint8_t test[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    struct myStruct struc;
    memcpy(struc.arr, test, sizeof(struc.arr));


    printf("struc.arr[] = ");

    for( i=0; i < sizeof(test); i++ )
    {
        printf("%d ", struc.arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Minor: when there is ever a chance that the source and the destination may be of differing sizes with `memcpy()`, recommend using the size of the destination as the _size_: `memcpy(struc.arr, test, sizeof struc.arr);`  (or use a compile time test to insure both sizes match)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a segmentation fault because you didn't allocate your struct pointer.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    uint8_t test[10] = {0};
    struct myStruct *struct = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));
    if (!struc)
        return -1;
    memcpy(struc->arr, test, sizeof(test));
    free(struc);
    return 0;
}
```

But, as @Chimera mentioned, you perfectly can not use a point and directly a heap-allocated structure, and access to its inner fields with the `.` operator

Comment: Don't forget to `free(struc)`

Comment: My bad. I update the code according to your wise advice.

Comment: Also, don't use `struct` as a variable name - it's a C keyword. Notice that the OP used `struc` instead.